# Binding element 'ReactNode' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying something really simple here. I just initialized a new project using `create-react-app app --template typescript`, and created a new file in `src/components/MyButton/MyButton.tsx` with this content:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

const MyButton = ({ children: ReactNode }) => {
  return <div>MyButton</div>;
};

export default MyButton;
```

This line `const MyButton = ({ children: ReactNode }) => {` is highlighted with the error from the title.

> Binding element 'ReactNode' implicitly has an 'any' type

`package.json` looks like this

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Do I need to install some other library?

I tried installing, as described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/):

```bash
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Still same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the props object, not the values inside it directly.

Try this instead:

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

const MyButton = ({ children }: {children: ReactNode}) => {
  return <div>MyButton</div>;
};

export default MyButton;
```